# filters are not being executed

Tags: php, laminas-api-tools

I'm writing a PHP 5.6 application using apigility 1.0.4 and zend framework 2.3.3

with apigility I created a new reset service called drink
and created a filed called "drink_flavor".

I used the following filters:

```
Zend\Filter\StringToLower
Zend\Filter\StringTrim
```

now I use postman to test it.

so i configured the url to `http://url/drink`
I'm sending post data with raw json with the following text:

```
{"drink_flavor" : " AAA"}
```

as you can see i have a space at the beginning and the letters are capital.

now if my controller code i have the following:

```
public function create($data)
{
    die(var_export($data,1));
}
```

so i'm just printing the data.

if I understood everything correctly instead of getting ' AAA' i should have gotten 'aaa'
because of my filters but I still got the unmodified data which is " AAA".

any ideas what's missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pull the data from you `InputFilter` to get the filtered data.

So inside your listener:

```
// Get filtered data
$inputFilter = $this->getInputFilter();
$data = $inputFilter->getValues();
```

And continue to use that `$data` array instead.

The `$data` param in your create method is the raw/unfiltered `POST` data.
You should be careful using that `$data` as a source for your methods since anything sent by the client will be in there.

I think this is not so clearly explained in the Apigility documentation and I think that a lot of users make this mistake. I wrote about this in [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-skeleton/issues/75).